# How to set correct file permissions for sqlite3.db for django website

Tags: django, apache, sqlite, ubuntu, permissions

I am new to django and in the process of deploying a test site to a target production server.
I have set-up and run the test locally, all is good. I have moved spawned a new ubuntu server, transferred the files, made the necessary config changes and the site runs fine.

However, when I go to register a new user of even to login as an existing one the server throws a 500 error.  (i have masked my IP).

```
[Wed Jan 22 12:08:15.233965 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19296:tid 139823034910464] [remote x.x.x.x:60559]     return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
[Wed Jan 22 12:08:15.234022 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 19296:tid 139823034910464] [remote x.x.x.x:60559] django.db.utils.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

On inspection I noticed that the sqlite3.db file had only root permisions. (I uploaded as root user via ftp).

I modified the ownership and permissions for the file, they are now:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data 151552 Jan 22 15:29 db.sqlite3
```

I have confirmed that www-data is running the site using apachectl -S

VirtualHost configuration:

```
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
.......
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

What am I missing?

On a further note, should I be change the ownership and permissions of the /var/www folder tree to be all owned and grouped to "www-data"?

Comment: I have solved my own problem!  The issue was the permissions to the folder holding the db.sqlite3 file.  I updated these to match the file and the issue was resolved.

Comment: So is it correct that www-data only needs to be the group, and a user (root or other) can be the owner?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  So long as the apache user ('www-data' in my case) as the group has write permissions to the folder and the db.sqlite3 file then it will work. The owner can be anything (root in my case).   However, please bear in mind, I am no expert. There are probably more security considerations that could and should be done.